# Using bootstrap to left-align columns using col- and flexbox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, python-sphinx

I have a bootstrap based  website where I would like to display a table and an image next to each other. This section comes directly after a heading and I would like for the table to be aligned with the heading.

Currently there is an offset between where the heading starts and the table begins, this is because the table is aligned centrally inside of the column instead of left-aligned.

In my html it looks as following:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.col-6-hard {
  max-width: 300px
}


/* standard bootstrap col-6 element, mentioned here for clarification but actually defined in the bootstrap sourcecode*/

.col-6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}


/* the docutils class seems to not have an influence according to chrome inspect*/

.container>div {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h1>heading</h1>
<div class="grid docutils container">
  <div class="col-6-hard docutils container">
    ..table..
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 docutils container">
    image
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in two columns on the website, the items in which are both center aligned. I tried adding float-left as a class, text-align:left to both .grid and col- as well as a variation of those, but nothing seems to be able to change the alignment. increasing the width in col-6-hard seems to somewhat work when it comes to moving the table more to the left, but I would like it to be entirely left aligned if possible.

This code is generated inside of a sphinx rst website using the pydata_sphinx_theme, which is based on bootstrap 4. It encompasses two sidebars and the abovementioned div is embedded inside of the middle column.

Is there a good solution to align the col elements as well as their contents?

Comment: Bootstrap has a whole array of [flexbox classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex) for alignment and sizing. I wouldn't be rolling my own, nor would I be overriding base layout classes. That's a recipe for frustration down the road. You're also missing a critical row element.

Comment: I'd write up a solution, but you've put more effort into describing what you've tried than what you're actually after. It's not clear to me. Please revise to do that.

Comment: I cannot visualize what you want. Aligned how?

Comment: @StevePiercy I would like for the table to be left aligned and on the same level as the header above it

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me. Sorry, I guess I need a drawing.